# How to specify timeout for firebase.put() in python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi to update the values in my realtime database. When the network is stable everything runs fine but when the network is unstable the firebase.put() function which updates the database keeps on waiting for a long time like very long and the program gets stuck for that time period. Is there any way to specify the timeout value in python?

Comment: One option might be to start a second thread that does the transmission to Firebase and you could pass values to it via a Python queue to transmit onwards to Firebase without it holding up your main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module `func-timeout`:

https://pypi.org/project/func-timeout/

You can install the package using the following command:

```
pip install func-timeout
```

For example:

```
from func_timeout import func_timeout, FunctionTimedOut

…

try:

doitReturnValue = func_timeout(5, doit, args=(‘arg1’, ‘arg2’))
except FunctionTimedOut:

print ( “doit(‘arg1’, ‘arg2’) could not complete within 5 seconds and was terminated.\n”)
except Exception as e:

# Handle any exceptions that doit might raise here
```

Comment: @NiteshSingh no problem, since the answer helped you, please mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful thank you!